# Is it a G flat or a G natural?

Tags: chords, notation, keyboard, key-signatures, accidentals

I've got a doubt here. Do I play G flat or G natural??
The accidental doesn't come in till the 3rd beat while the key signature does not have G flat, while the lyric has an accidental but at the second quaver beat, so that means even if the lyric counts for the instrument part, the note still stays with a G flat, while the chord above says it's a G Flat chord.
Here's a photo: [image]

Comment: This looks like a typo in the score. As written, it's a G, but all other information in the score suggests it should be a G-flat. What's the piece?

Comment: Street Life - The Crusaders feat. Randy Crawford.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some more of that chart.

Comment: Which note are you referring to?

Comment: @Richard "This looks like a typo in the score" an *accidental accidental*, then?

Answer (score 9):

For starters, it's no G♭ chord. As it states, it's D♭m7, with a G♭ bass note.

Which means, assuming you're asking about the G in the bass clef (note on beat 2), it must be G♭, which means it's a typo.

EDIT: just checked another sheet music, and the D♭m7 is beat 1, then beat 2 is G♭9. so it would appear - a. it's not a slash chord. b. the second chord is G♭9, and the bass note is in fact G♭. A simple (common) ii>V>I just in that bar.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. So, does that mean that I play G flat or natural??  I don't think it is a typo... This is an exam-piece for Trinity Rock & Pop Grade 6, not saying that they cannot make a mistake, but this book has been in the syllabus since last 3 years and this is the latest publication, don't think they would make such a mistake... So what to do?? Still I appreciate your help. Thank you .

Comment: A typo is a typing error. Here, the flat sign has been missed out, by mistake I guess. But that bass note will be Gb, not the G that's printed. It is worth looking at other copies of the same song, I'm sure the accidental would be in some of them - unless they'rve all copied from the same mistake!

Comment: The Randy Crawford recording clearly has a Gb in the bass, not a G. Based on that, the style of the song, chord symbols and harmonic function it is definitely a Gb. Typos can appear anywhere, even in published music.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - good move, listening to the track.Didn't get that far.

Comment: May be this is not a "typo" but a test to see if you are able to identify a typo. ;)

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli in that case we all passed! :)

Comment: You remind me of my friend. Whenever he wouldn't get or understand anything, he would say it's a test for the student to go through it. I'm not saying you're wrong and I think this IS a typo. But it was just that I went back in time reading this  I appreciate all of your help. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Ishan.J - are you sure it's grade 6? Trinity says it's 7...I've emailed them, and await the response.

Comment: Yes, it's Grade 6. I've been preparing for the exam since last 2 months. Here's a source - In the contents you can see the exam songs https://shop.trinitycollege.com/shop/prod/Various-Trinity-Rock-Pop-2018-Keyboards-Grade-6/2301980

Comment: Ah, the grade VII is the high *vocal*  version!

Answer (score 2):

Dbm7-Gb7-Cb = iim7-V7-I in Cb: this makes sense as progression. And the chord sign Dbm7/Gb says the 2nd beat is still Dbm7 but above Gb. I agree with Tim.